# Hide table column from property pane (WebPart)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts, react, react-webpart

I am still new into the WebPart development so bare with me:

I have created a WebPart consisting of table and I have several toggles in the settings that can show hide a column in the table. Somehow I cannot get the part how I can make the hook between the settings and the table itself.

So basically my question is: ***How I can detect the "change" event of the toggle in the property pane and do something(eg. call custom function) when it happens? Like is there a standard to do it?***

I have created the WebPart with the use of yo `@microsoft/sharepoint` and I am using React as JavaScript framework.

Any help and ideas are appreciated.

Best regards,

Dimitar Georgiev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a method present for detecting property pane change,

onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,

[image]

then there is also the , refresh method inside the sp context.

[image]

You should also make sure your webpart properties were tied up with a state in your components, cause changing the state will re render the webpart, so basically updating a webpart property that has a component state listening to it will re render the data.

Here is an additional [resource](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240694/react-state-in-property-pane).

Hope it helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank for the answer! It helped me a lot to figure it out :)

Comment: Awesome! Grateful it helped! Happy Coding! :)